# Android layout: How to put this ViewGroup inside a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android

Hi how to make this code works? I want this class CameraSurfaceView to put inside a relative layout?

Code:

```
public class CameraSurfaceView extends ViewGroup  implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    private final String TAG = "Preview";

    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Size mPreviewSize;
    private List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        addView(mSurfaceView);

        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    }
     ...
}
```

MainActivity;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    RelativeLayout rlCamWrapper;
    CameraSurfaceView cameraSurfaceView;


    private SurfaceView surfaceView;

    private boolean isRecording = false;



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hide the window title.
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        cameraSurfaceView = new CameraSurfaceView(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    ...
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    >

    <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/videoView1" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"/>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/surfaceViewWrapper" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5">

        <SurfaceView 
            android:id="@+id/surfaceView2" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

thanks ahead for your help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply changing `<SurfaceView` in your xml with `<your.package.CameraSurfaceView` should do the trick. Then just get it with `findViewById()` in your code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    RelativeLayout rlCamWrapper;
    CameraSurfaceView cameraSurfaceView;


    private SurfaceView surfaceView;

    private boolean isRecording = false;



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hide the window title.
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // this is the important part
        cameraSurfaceView = (CameraSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView2);
    }
    ...
}
```

also, make sure you overload the other constructors for your view (something like this):

```
public class CameraSurfaceView extends ViewGroup  implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    private final String TAG = "Preview";

    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Size mPreviewSize;
    private List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        addView(mSurfaceView);

        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    }

    public CameraSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        ...
    }

    public CameraSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        ...
    }
     ...
}
```

Comment: sorry @zrgiu but I'm really new to android, I get what you mean, but I don't know to to code it. Can you please give me some sample code? This is what i have in xml: <com.sample.video.CameraSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/cameraView"
    />

Comment: hey @marvz, check out the updated response with code. Is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: I got this error @zrgiu: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.video/com.sample.video.MainActivity}. android.view.InflateException

Answer (score 0):

No need to create the instance

```
       cameraSurfaceView = new CameraSurfaceView(this);
```

Just set the layout through setContentView. Also in your xml set the

```
      <SurfaceView in your xml with <your.package.CameraSurfaceView
```

And your done.